# Storing objects in an array and retrieving using PHP

Tags: php, oop, symfony, zend-framework

I have two classes called Edge and Graph, I need to send set of edge objects (out side those classes) to Graph object by looping and retrieve from Graph Object.

Graph Class

```
class Graph
{

/**
 * Array of edge objects
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $edges;

/**
 * Set edges of the graph
 *
 * @param Edge edge object
 */
public function __construct(Edge $edge)
{
    $this->setEdges($edge);
}

/**
 * Get edges
 *
 * @return array array of edge objects
 */
public function getEdges()
{
    return $this->edges;
}

/**
 * Set Edges
 *
 * @param Edge Edge object
 */
public function setEdges(Edge $edge)
{

$this->edges[] = $edge;

}

}
```

Looping through edges,

```
$edges = array(
        array("point1" => "a", "point2" => "b", "value" => 7),
        array("point1" => "a", "point2" => "c", "value" => 9),
        array("point1" => "a", "point2" => "f", "value" => 14.00)
)

$graph = null;
foreach ($edges as $edge) {
    $edgeObj = new Edge($edge['point1'], $edge['point2'], $edge['value']);
    $graph = new Graph($edgeObj);

}
```

But $graph returns only last Edge object, I know it's because I overwrite $graph. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered it yourself perfectly. You're overwriting `$graph` with each iteration of your loop, with a completely new instance of a `Graph` object.

First, remove your constructor to allow you to create an instance of `Graph` without first needing an `Edge` instance (ie, outside your loop), then use your already written `setEdges()` method to add each newly created `Edge` instance to your array in the class.

Then, change your code to this:

```
$edges = array(
        array("point1" => "a", "point2" => "b", "value" => 7),
        array("point1" => "a", "point2" => "c", "value" => 9),
        array("point1" => "a", "point2" => "f", "value" => 14.00)
)

$graph = new Graph();
    foreach ($edges as $edge) {
        $edgeObj = new Edge($edge['point1'], $edge['point2'], $edge['value']);
        $graph->setEdges($edgeObj);

    }
```

Comment: then it will be an array of Graph object, But I need one Graph object which consists of many Edges as an array.

Comment: @MDeSilva please see my revised answer. By removing the constructor, you can create the item without first needing an `Edge` object, which allows you to just call your `setEdges` method in the loop on the existing `Graph` object, such that it won't be overwritten.

Comment: Leprichaun, Yes you are right, to be frank I was doing the same. and I think there is no any other way. Thanks